# HTML DOM Parser возвращает False

Tags: php

Использую библиотеку

> SIMPLE.HTML.DOM.PARSER

При парсинге корректного URL var_dump() возвращает bool (false)

```
$document = str_get_html(file_get_contents('https://coinmarketcap.com/exchanges/volume/24-hour/'));
var_dump($document);
```

Comment: Используй headless браузер.

Answer (score 1):

Ну видимо там и правда ничего нет, когда грузится ибо сайт динамический.

Можно пробовать брать через **[cURL](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php)** и работать с ним:

```
$url  = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/exchanges/volume/24-hour/';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Создаем DOM объект
$html_base = new simple_html_dom();
// загружаем HTML из строки
$html_base->load($str);

// возьмем из таблицы все ссылки
foreach($html_base->find('.table.table-condensed tr td a') as $element) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $element->href );
    echo "</pre>";
}

$html_base->clear(); 
unset($html_base);
```

Выведет

```
/exchanges/bitfinex/
/currencies/bitcoin/
https://www.bitfinex.com/trading/BTCUSD
/currencies/ethereum/
https://www.bitfinex.com/trading/ETHUSD
/currencies/bitcoin-cash/
https://www.bitfinex.com/trading/BCHBTC
/currencies/neo/
https://www.bitfinex.com/trading/NEOUSD
/currencies/bitcoin-cash/
https://www.bitfinex.com/trading/BCHUSD
/currencies/ripple/
https://www.bitfinex.com/trading/XRPUSD
/currencies/ethereum/
https://www.bitfinex.com/trading/ETHBTC
/currencies/zcash/
https://www.bitfinex.com/trading/ZECUSD
/currencies/litecoin/

и т.д.
```